# Get data from program that launched from vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have a vscode extension that launches an executable, i know how to pass data from vscode to my program but not the other way around.

```
// class that launches the exe
class Execute {
  constructor(private _extensionPath: string) {}

  public Launch() {
    console.log('213');
    Process.exec(
      `WpfApp1.exe true`,
      { cwd: this._extensionPath },
      (error: Error, stdout: string, stderr: string) => {
        if (stdout.length === 0) {
          return;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}


// calling the class
let exe = new Execute(
vscode.extensions.getExtension('author.extension').extensionPath
);
exe.Launch();
```

c# receiving data

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        test_p = e.Args[0];
        if (test_p == "true")
        {

        }
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("fail"); }
}
```

how can i send data from the c# application to the vscode extension?
calling a function in vscode would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also run a executable with c#:

```
public static string[] Cmd(bool xWaitForExecution, params string[] xCommands)
{
    //PROCESS CMD
    if (xCommands == null || xCommands.Length == 0) return null;
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;          //STD INPUT
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;         //STD OUTPUT
    info.RedirectStandardError = true;          //STD ERROR
    Process process = Process.Start(info);

    //WRITE COMMANDS
    using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            foreach (string cmd in xCommands)
                sw.WriteLine(cmd);

    //GET OUTPUT & ERROR
    if (!xWaitForExecution) return null;
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();     //OUTPUT
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();       //ERROR
    string exit = process.ExitCode.ToString();              //EXIT CODE
    process.Close();
    return new string[] { output, error, exit };
}
```

The function runs cmd64.exe and it should use like:

```
//Call Cmd, true means the c# application will wait for the complete execute of your executable (needed to obtain output values)
string[] ret = Cmd(true, "\\mypath\\my.exe -Argument1 -Argument2"); //Passing arguments depends on your executable
string output = ret[0];
Console.WriteLine(ret[0]) //printed arguments from your executable (for instance python: print("Argument1"))
```

It is not completly clear why you need the VS Code extension to execute an executable. This is a working alternative to run executables on windows from c#.

Comment: i want to add a custom menu to vscode and i saw that some one else made an executable that gets called from vscode so in order to make an executable i started to learn c# yesterday, i can call my menu from vscode and also give it starting arguments, the only thing left to to is to send some data back to vscode, thats why i need to start the exe from vscode, there might be another way to add custom ui but i didn't find it if it exists (i spend a long time going through the docs)

Comment: @Syler okay and you program your custom menu in c# correct?

Comment: In order to generate an output for vs code you have to use `Console.WriteLine("your output")` in your c# application. After that you have to capture the the **STDOUT** of the process which running by the vs code. As result you should get the `Console.WriteLine` commands as string. Try to looking for _how to capture stdout in a vs code extension_ or somethink like that.

Comment: thank you i have it working now, i will answer my question myself when i have time.

Answer (score 0):

Send Data:

```
 private void AnyEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      const String output = "testOutput,testOutput2";
      Console.Write(output);
    }
```

Receive Data:

```
 import * as Process from 'child_process';
 // put the code below in a class or function.
 Process.exec(
  `app.exe input`,
  { cwd: "Path to folder of the executable" },
  (error, stdout: string, stderr: string) => {
    const output = stdout.split(','); //it only outputs data after the exe is closed!?
    if (output[0] === 'testOutput') {
      console.log('Output: == "testOutput"');
    }
  }
);
```

Example [Project](https://github.com/TheRealSyler/exe-com)  should work after running `npm i` if not open an issue or comment below.